# ios7 - boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize not returning the needed label height

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, custom-cell

I'm trying to resize my custom cell in a tebleview. But with no success.
The NSlog at the end returns:

```
2013-12-19 18:51:40.785 DevCloud[15750:70b] 20.281000
2013-12-19 18:51:40.786 DevCloud[15750:70b] 41.565002
2013-12-19 18:51:40.787 DevCloud[15750:70b] 20.281000
2013-12-19 18:51:40.787 DevCloud[15750:70b] 41.565002
```

Here are my 2 method implementations for cell and cell height:
How to make it work? :)

```
 (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TimelineCell";
    TLRKTimelineCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.sampleLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer fermentum, neque sed viverra vestibulum, arcu ligula imperdiet turpis, blandit consectetur quam neque eu urna. Duis rhoncus accumsan eleifend. Vestibulum ac nunc aliquet, semper felis at, suscipit tortor. Etiam nec mauris nunc.";

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TLRKTimelineCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TimelineCell"];

    CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(cell.sampleLabel.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:17];

    CGRect textRect = [cell.sampleLabel.text boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];

    NSLog(@"%f",textRect.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f",textRect.size.width);

    return textRect.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that the method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you should pass your for example `NSArray` for `indexPath.row` in this case i wrote your `cell.textLabel.text` and it should work:

```
  ...

 NSString *string = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer fermentum, neque sed viverra vestibulum, arcu ligula imperdiet turpis, blandit consectetur quam neque eu urna. Duis rhoncus accumsan eleifend. Vestibulum ac nunc aliquet, semper felis at, suscipit tortor. Etiam nec mauris nunc.";

 CGRect textRect = [string boundingRectWithSize:boundingSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];

 ...
```

and I recommend to change: `NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading` with: `NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin`

Comment: Yes :) i fix these myself :).